# Any freeware IIS log analyzer?

Tags: iis, iis-6, log-files, logparser, logging

It would be nice to use ASP.NET, but PHP is ok too, and should be hosted in IIS6.

**EDIT:** the logs are from our intranet site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Analog: http://www.analog.cx/

Also, check out this blog entry:  http://weblogs.asp.net/steveschofield/archive/2007/09/04/log-analsyis-software-for-iis.aspx

Comment: While not updated in quite some time, Analog is an excellent program.

Comment: a bit old, but very fast and gets the job done.

Comment: we use analog, but indihiang is promising (although the current beta is almost useless)

Comment: Analog appears to have disappeared off of the internet, and the blog post link no longer works.

Answer (score 16):

We use awstats.  http://awstats.sourceforge.net/

Comment: +1 for awstats.  It's as good as the old webtrends reports we used to run, and has modules for additional functionality.  Plus the cost can't be beat!

Answer (score 9):

The Microsoft [IIS resource kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=56FC92EE-A71A-4C73-B628-ADE629C89499&displaylang=en) has a log parser that lets your run SQL like queries on IIS Logs.

I also rate awstats if your dont know what your looking for & would just like some stock reports.

I believe [google analytic](http://www.google.com/analytics/)s is probably the best value you'll get for free, you dont even need your log then :)

What are you looking for by analyzing logs?

Comment: Just more or less detailed user usage of different sections of the sites, nothing special. But easier configuration for reporting on IIS is a big bonus.

Comment: The IIS Resource Kit is a nice way to query a .log file like SQL and find the top used resources.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution to your problem (as clarified in your comment) is NOT to analyze the logfile at all.  Use **[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics)**.  It will give you all the details about traffic you're likely to need and even some customizations (via the API, that is a simple javascript call) necessary to track stuff that's typically un-trackable via log parsing anyway (client-side clicks etc.)

There are very few use cases that REQUIRE customized or DIY log parsing (even if they're free).  You can always keep the logs archived for a rainy day if you run into one of those cases.

Comment: +1 but, my mistake, I didn't mention that the logs belong to our intranet site. Also the content is not totally under my control, so I can't use a counter like Google Analytics or Statcounter.

Comment: I found Google Analytics incredibly inaccurate.  It severely under-reports traffic.

Answer (score 3):

there is al easy alternative. make IIS to log to an MSSQL table. After you can work with it like a normal database. search for a ODBC conection on the root of you site.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do log analysis for compliance reasons (detecting attacks, etc) I would suggest using the open source OSSEC (can't post a link because I am a new user, but just google for it).

Answer (score 1):

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344693 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915207

I'm looking at checking out the accepted answer from the latter question sometime in the next week.

Update: I've been using the free version of Smarter Stats for a while now and despite some minor challenges getting it set up, I love it.

Answer (score 1):

Super easy to install and a user friendly interface: [SmarterStats](http://www.smartertools.com/SmarterStats/Free-Web-Analytics.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

http://indihiang.codeplex.com/

> Indihiang Project is a web log analyzing tool. The tool analyzes IIS and Apache Web servers in comprehensive graphs and reports.
>
> Project Features
>
> - .NET Framework with C# as programming language
> - Web Log Viewer and analyzer
> - Web Log Consolidation
> - Web Log Real-time monitoring
> - Support for IIS6 and IIS7
> - Trend Data Analysis
> - Reporting

Answer (score 1):

Try
[piwik.org](http://piwik.org)

> Piwik is downloadable, Free/Libre (GPLv3 licensed) real time web
>   analytics software. It provides you with detailed reports on your
>   website visitors; the search engines and keywords they used, the
>   language they speak, your popular pages, and much more.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use [Baretail](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/index.php)

It has a free version and allows you to use **regular expressions** against large files (over 2gb)

Google analytics alone is not enough. there are people without javascript enabled and/or block it with adblock plugins and the http errors from iis.