# Analyse IIS Log Files

Tags: iis, log-files, analytics

I've got an IIS6 server with a boat load of log files.

What good tools are there that I can't use to get a decent amount of detail from the logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can depend on which format of log file you've chosen and which details are logged (this is of course configurable), **but** I would try,

- Webalizer http://www.webalizer.com/

And for converting between the various log file formats or ther detailed analysis I think you can use,

- [Microsoft Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07)

This site looks full of information, [Logparser Forums : The Official Microsoft IIS Site](http://forums.iis.net/default.aspx?GroupID=51)

And this if you're asking on **ServerFault** then this is probably worth a read, [Coding Horror: Microsoft LogParser](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000369.html) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

See this question:  [Any freeware IIS log analyzer?](https://serverfault.com/questions/13676/any-freeware-iis-log-analyzer)