# Software for analyzing IIS logs?

Tags: iis, logging

I have a ton of IIS monthly logs.  Can someone recommend software that can help me analyze them (e.g. visitors, os/browser statistics, all the standard stuff)?

I'd like a piece of software that does not require me to setup a server or anything complicated.  Simply point it to a file or folder and it'll do the rest.  Back in the day (90s) there was something like that, but I can't find it now.

Thanks

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/13676/any-freeware-iis-log-analyzer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used http://www.weblogexpert.com/lite.htm. It is free and quite good. You install it on Windows like any other program and point it to folder with logs.

There are standard and pro versions which you have to pay for, but lite is also often sufficient.

There is no more lite version which was free at the time.
"There is a free fully-functional 30-day trial version of WebLog Expert." Note that it is free only for 30 days.

Comment: That's it.  That's the software I used back in the day.  Absolutely perfect.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

I used to run [Awffull](http://www.stedee.id.au/awffull/) on a linux box to process all the logs from multiples IIS servers. It was very fast.

Answer (score 2):

You can query the log files from their storage with the free edition of [SpectX](https://www.spectx.com). There's a built-in parser for IIS logs and many sample queries listed here:

[Analyzing IIS logs](https://www.spectx.com/articles/analyzing-iis-logs)

[Analyzing Exchange and Activesync activities](https://www.spectx.com/articles/parse-iis-logs-to-analyze-exchange-outlook-web-access-and-activesync-activities)