# IIS - how to track IPs and amount of connections per hour / day

Tags: iis, iis-7, logging

I run couple sites on IIS 7 and I would like to see which IPs accessed my sites and how many connections (page views) they generated per hour and day.

What would be my best solution to obtain this information? (in easy to read and organized manner)

Comment: A good paid solution is always Google analytics.  It would give you all of the basic metrics that you would be looking for in a production environment.

Comment: Google Analytics is actually a good *free* solution.

Comment: Due to user privacy concerns, Google Analytics doesn't report on personally identifiable information, including a visitor's IP address. Instead, Google Analytics provides aggregated data to help you make informed business decisions

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're looking for a free solution:

1. Your question is already answered: [ServerFault: Any freeware IIS log analyzer?](https://serverfault.com/questions/13676/any-freeware-iis-log-analyzer)
2. I've used the old ones like [Analog](http://www.analog.cx/) and [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/), and [this one (Piwik)](http://piwik.org/) looks more up to date.
3. Nowadays people tend to use services like the free [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).